# How to reliably check if I am above a certain CentOS version (CentOS 7) in a Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, rhel, centos7

I have been given a task to port a bunch of our internal applications from CentOS6 to CentOS7. With this move, we are changing our dependencies from external packages that we have repackaged ourselves to official upstream version of the packages.

Because of this I am looking for a reliable piece of python2.7 code that will do this:

```
if CentOS version >= 7:
    do things the new way
else:
    do things the deprecated way
```

It will be used for autogenerating .spec files to make RPMs.

I've been looking at things like parsing `/etc/redhat-release` but that seems a little bit unreliable for what I want. Is there a better way?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54987/how-to-know-centos-version) `rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' centos-release` is the best way for a Major version. The command would have to be called in a subprocess.

Comment: I believe CentOS 6 uses Python 2.6. So, unless your users changed this, you could simply check `sys.version_info`

Comment: @JBernando,  Just to clarify sys.version_info returns the version information for python when I tried it.  Did you mean that for checking if the op is on 2.6 or 2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try:

```
In [1]: import platform

In [2]: platform.linux_distribution()
Out[2]: ('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server', '6.5', 'Santiago')

In [3]: dist = platform.linux_distribution()

In [4]: "Red Hat" in dist[0] and dist[1].split('.')[0] == '6'
Out[4]: True

In [5]:
```

hth

Comment: Totally forgot about this >.< and it's a much better answer. Just would update it to use the newer `.linux_distribution()`

Comment: Hi Kelvin, thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I wanted! About to implement it now

Comment: Actually, this has the disadvantage for me that if ran on another linux distribution it wont fail. EG platform.linux_distribution()[1] on ubuntu returns '14.04' I will probably go for CasualDemon's answer as it is better in my case.

Comment: @Kevin, I updated the solution to check for both Red Hat and split on the major version of the platform.  I hope this helps more, you can check on individual parts inside of it.  You can wrap that in one large if statement.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Ignore mine, use @Kelvin's

Expanding on my comment to add relevant code. This is based off [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54987/how-to-know-centos-version)

```
import subprocess

version = subprocess.check_output(["rpm", "-q", "--queryformat", "'%{VERSION}'", "centos-release"])

if int(version) >= 7:
    # do something
```

Comment: Hi CasualDemon, thanks for the answer. I found I had to use: `centos_version = re.sub('[^0-9]','', subprocess.check_output(["rpm", "-q", "--queryformat", "'%{VERSION}'", "centos-release"]))` to avoid errors like `invalid literal for int() with base 10`